# How can I convert T-SQL syntax, which has written by CASE WHEN, to pivot or window functions

Tags: sql-server, pivot

How can I convert T-SQL syntax, which has written by `CASE WHEN`, to `PIVOT` or `window functions` with following code:

```
SELECT 
    T.TaskID,
    SUM(CASE WHEN T.LogDate<'2016-02-04' AND T.TaskStatusID=2 THEN ISNULL(DA_CHILD.Value,0)*(T.DoneScore/100) ELSE 0 END) PreAmount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN T.LogDate>='2016-02-04' AND T.LogDate<='2017-02-04' AND T.TaskStatusID=2 THEN ISNULL(DA_CHILD.Value,0)*(T.DoneScore/100) ELSE 0 END) CurAmount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN T.LogDate>'2017-02-04' AND T.TaskStatusID=2 THEN ISNULL(DA_CHILD.Value,0)*(T.DoneScore/100) ELSE 0 END) AfterAmount
FROM 
    NetTasks$ T
    INNER JOIN NetDeviceActions DA ON DA.DeviceActionID=T.DeviceActionID
    INNER JOIN NetActionParents AP ON AP.ParentID=DA.ActionID
    INNER JOIN NetDeviceActions DA_CHILD ON DA_CHILD.ActionID=AP.ChildID AND 
                                            DA_CHILD.DeviceID=DA.DeviceID AND 
                                            DA_CHILD.ContractInfoID=DA.ContractInfoID

WHERE 
      T.ParentTaskID = 0 AND 
      T.FinishDate<='2017-01-07' AND 
      DA.ContractInfoID=15

GROUP BY 
      T.TaskID, T.DoneScore,T.FinishDate
```

This is my result:

```
TaskID PreAmount CurAmount AfterAmount
686170   0          0          0
655768   NULL       0          0
734520   0         NULL        0
682661   0         NULL        0
```

Comment: Provide the sampled data what you want to show and what your query returns. so that the people can answer your question easily and quickly.

Comment: Sampled data not important. I want to find out is there any way to switch on pivot or window functions.

Comment: Sample data is important as I don't understand what your data looks like and what your desired output is. Your question is too broad as it stands, please edit it.

Comment: @Tanner I've edited.

Comment: Why? is there an issue with the current implementation? (This helps us not make the same mistake in any other implementation) The only issue I see with it is the hard coded dates.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid for increase fetching.

Comment: Do you mean improved performance? Any performance issue is more likely to be due to lack of indexes. I doubt very much whether a rewrite using PIVOT will improve performance

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Our manager has forced us to convert to pivot or window function

Comment: Your manager is clueless. To convert to a pivot, you _first_ have to transform the data into a different format anyway. I will pose an incomplete answer now and finish it tomorrow if you still haven't worked it out (sorry it's late here)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the first transformation that you have to put your data through:

Please test this for errors first

```
SELECT 
    T.TaskID,
    CASE 
    WHEN T.LogDate<'2016-02-04' AND T.TaskStatusID=2 
    THEN 'PreAmount'
    WHEN T.LogDate>='2016-02-04' AND T.LogDate<='2017-02-04' 
    AND T.TaskStatusID=2 THEN 'CurAmount'
    WHEN T.LogDate>'2017-02-04' AND T.TaskStatusID=2 THEN 'AfterAmount' 
    END As Type,
    ISNULL(DA_CHILD.Value,0)*(T.DoneScore/100) Amount
FROM 
    NetTasks$ T
    INNER JOIN NetDeviceActions DA ON DA.DeviceActionID=T.DeviceActionID
    INNER JOIN NetActionParents AP ON AP.ParentID=DA.ActionID
    INNER JOIN NetDeviceActions DA_CHILD ON DA_CHILD.ActionID=AP.ChildID 
    AND DA_CHILD.DeviceID=DA.DeviceID 
    AND DA_CHILD.ContractInfoID=DA.ContractInfoID
WHERE 
      T.ParentTaskID = 0 AND 
      T.FinishDate<='2017-01-07' AND 
      DA.ContractInfoID=15
```

Now if you take a look at this page:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

The query above takes place of `(<SELECT query that produces the data>)`

So when we follow those instructions and look at some examples, we come up with this:

```
SELECT 
TaskID,
[PreAmount],[CurAmount],[AfterAmount]
FROM (
SELECT 
    T.TaskID,
    CASE 
    WHEN T.LogDate<'2016-02-04' AND T.TaskStatusID=2 
    THEN 'PreAmount'
    WHEN T.LogDate>='2016-02-04' AND T.LogDate<='2017-02-04' 
    AND T.TaskStatusID=2 THEN 'CurAmount'
    WHEN T.LogDate>'2017-02-04' AND T.TaskStatusID=2 THEN 'c' 
    END As Type,
    ISNULL(DA_CHILD.Value,0)*(T.DoneScore/100) Amount
FROM 
    NetTasks$ T
    INNER JOIN NetDeviceActions DA ON DA.DeviceActionID=T.DeviceActionID
    INNER JOIN NetActionParents AP ON AP.ParentID=DA.ActionID
    INNER JOIN NetDeviceActions DA_CHILD ON DA_CHILD.ActionID=AP.ChildID 
    AND DA_CHILD.DeviceID=DA.DeviceID 
    AND DA_CHILD.ContractInfoID=DA.ContractInfoID
WHERE 
      T.ParentTaskID = 0 AND 
      T.FinishDate<='2017-01-07' AND 
      DA.ContractInfoID=15
) As SRC
PIVOT
(
SUM(Amount)
FOR Type IN [PreAmount],[CurAmount],[AfterAmount]
) As PivotTable
```

Here are all the problems with this:

- You are not going to see any performance improvement here
- Your code is more complicated and less maintainable

Problems with original query:

- it's full of hard coded dates
- `SUM`ing a rate usually gives you a nonsense number. Usually you sum numerator and denominator first *then* divide. Maybe that's your real problem

PS the window function makes even less sense I can't even think of a sensible way to do that.